# ASP AJAX toolkit sliderextender with overflow:auto scrolling the page down  in Chrome

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome

I am using the ASP.NET Ajax toolkit slider extender inside a div which has a fixed height and set to overflow:auto. This is because I have numerous sliders in a table, and if the list gets very long then I want a scrollbar in the div. This renders fine in all browsers, however in Chrome and some versions of Firefox, if I scroll down to a slider and click on it then the outer (main page) scroll bar scrolls very far down the page where there is just white space. It is as if the outer scroll bar moves to where the slider would have been if the whole table was rendered on the page without the overflow:auto. Any ideas why this is happening and how to prevent it?